# Enforce the name of a case object

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given this code:

```
sealed trait Parent

case object GetOne extends Parent
case object GetTwo extends Parent
```

Is it possible in Scala to enforce those constraints:

1. `Parent` can only be extended by `case object`
2. The child `case object` of `Parent` must have their names start by `Get`.

Is it possible?

Comment: 1. afaik at best you can demand that parent is extended by `Product with Serializable with Singleton`. 2. I guess, you could make parent take some implicit parameter which would be resolved basing on the name of the child and make this implicit available only for names starting with get using some macro... but this is messed up.

Comment: Basically something like `sealed abstract class Parent[T: StartWithGet] { this: T with Product with Serializable with Singleton }` where `StartWithGet[T]` is provided by macro only for classes which name starts with get. But this is so evil.

Comment: Alternatively `StartsWithGet` in my answer can be defined via https://github.com/fthomas/singleton-ops `import shapeless.tag.@@` `import singleton.ops.{Require, StartsWith}` `trait StartsWithGet[S]` `object StartsWithGet { implicit def mkStartsWithGet[S <: String](implicit startsWith: Require[S StartsWith "Get"]): StartsWithGet[Symbol @@ S] = null }`

Answer (score 4):

> Parent can only be extended by case object

You may get close using [**Singleton**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Singleton.html).
*(as mentioned by @MateuszKubuszok)*

Here is an example:

```
sealed trait Foo extends Product with Serializable { self: Singleton => }
```

Then this works:

```
final case object A extends Foo
final case object B extends Foo
```

And this doesn't:

```
final case object A extends Foo
final case class B(blah: String) extends Foo
```

> The child case object of Parent must have their names start by Get.

Not using standard Scala.
Maybe with macros or something like that, but really feels like a strange requisite; do you plan to get those instances through reflection? or what is the reason to wanting that?

*(in any case, seems like something that may be better handled by code reviews and maybe a scalafix rule)*

Comment: Thank you ! That helps a lot

Answer (score 4):

Try macros (with Shapeless)

```
import shapeless.ops.{coproduct, hlist}
import shapeless.{Coproduct, HList, LabelledGeneric}
import shapeless.ops.union.{Keys, Values}

def check[A] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

class PartiallyApplied[A] {
  def apply[C <: Coproduct, K <: HList, V <: Coproduct]()(implicit
    labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, C],
    keys: Keys.Aux[C, K],
    values: Values.Aux[C, V],
    allKeysStartWithGet: hlist.LiftAll[StartsWithGet, K],
    allValuesAreObjects: coproduct.LiftAll[IsObject, V]
  ) = null
}

import shapeless.Witness
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait StartsWithGet[S]

object StartsWithGet {
  implicit def mkStartsWithGet[S <: Symbol]: StartsWithGet[S] = macro impl[S]

  def impl[S <: Symbol : c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val typ = weakTypeOf[S]
    val witness = c.inferImplicitValue(
      c.typecheck(tq"_root_.shapeless.Witness.Aux[$typ]", mode = c.TYPEmode).tpe,
      silent = false
    )
    val str = c.eval(c.Expr[Witness.Lt[scala.Symbol]](
      c.untypecheck(witness.duplicate)
    )).value.name

    if (str.startsWith("Get"))
      q"new StartsWithGet[$typ] {}"
    else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$str doesn't start with Get")
  }
}

trait IsObject[A]

object IsObject {
  implicit def mkIsObject[A]: IsObject[A] = macro impl[A]

  def impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val typ = weakTypeOf[A]
    if (typ.typeSymbol.isModuleClass)
      q"new IsObject[$typ] {}"
    else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$typ is not object")
  }
}

sealed trait Parent 
case object GetOne extends Parent
case object GetTwo extends Parent
check[Parent]() // compiles

sealed trait Parent
case object GetOne extends Parent
case object Two extends Parent
check[Parent]() // doesn't compile

sealed trait Parent
case object GetOne extends Parent
case class GetTwo() extends Parent
check[Parent]() // doesn't compile
```

---

Alternatively `StartsWithGet` can be defined via https://github.com/fthomas/singleton-ops

```
import shapeless.tag.@@ 
import singleton.ops.{Require, StartsWith} 

trait StartsWithGet[S] 
object StartsWithGet { 
  implicit def mkStartsWithGet[S <: String](implicit 
    startsWith: Require[S StartsWith "Get"]
  ): StartsWithGet[Symbol @@ S] = null 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Parent can only be extended by case object

In Scala 3 you could define an [enumeration](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html)

```
enum Parent {
  case GetOne, GetTwo
}
```

which forces the members to be effectively case objects.

Comment: I am in Scala 2.11 , 2.12